# MongoRepository same methods with diferent @Query

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

Using spring data mongo repository class, how can I do this? I need the same method twice but in one I need to exclude a field.

```
public interface Person extends MongoRepository<Person, String>{
        
    Optional<Person> findById(String id);

    @Query(fields="{ 'company': 0 }")
    Optional<Person> findById(String id);
}
```

This doesn't work because I can't have the same method twice, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises when you want to call the method. It would be ambiguous which method is being called.

If you want to use [`method overloading`](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods_overloading.asp) to have a same name for both of your methods, it is only possible if they have different parameters.

here is an example:

```java
public interface Person extends MongoRepository<Person, String>{
        
    Optional<Person> findById(String id);

    @Query(fields="{ 'company': 0 }")
    Optional<Person> findById(String id, Boolean exclude);
}
```